Safe Infrastructure UI returns 404
I'm trying to run Safe Infrastructure locally based on this doc: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md
After setting up the required configuration, I tried to access the web UI but it responded with 404 error. All the other services (cgw, txs, etc.) are accessible but the main UI doesn't work. How do I fix this?


Is docker / docker-compose up to date with the latest version? What exact URL are you trying to access (the UI should be accessible from http://localhost:8000). Thank you in advance for your answers  Best, Louis

Yes, docker is up to date and I tried to access through http://localhost:8000. All the other paths like /cfg or /events are accessible, but the root path(/) is giving me 404 errors. Are there any required env vars in the preconfigured ui.env file?

No, the infrastructure should be working correctly after the step setting up the master admins. I would suggest to delete all containers, delete the data folder in the repo, and try a fresh configuration again. If this does not work I would then recommend opening an issue here: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/issues trying to be as detailed as possible (with machine, OS and configuration details). Please let me know! Best, Louis
